# Is there really a proof that all context-free grammars can be parsed using a LL(1) grammar without backtracking?

Tags: reference-request, context-free-grammar, parsing

I was watching a youtube video on a parsing library that I have an interest in that you can find here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wreCg30pyts&t=1272s. What is interesting though is that at 30:57 someone new comes on and references an interesting proof claiming that all context-free grammars can be parsed using a LL(1) parser without backtracking. Is this really true? Can anyone point me to a proof of this?

Comment: You might want to add the reference request tag to your question

Comment: @IdioticShrike I don't know how to do that. I just created an account.

Comment: You just edit your question; I’ve submitted an edit for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is interesting though is that at 30:57 someone new comes on and references an interesting proof claiming that all context-free grammars can be parsed using a LL(1) parser without backtracking.

That's not what he says, as far as I can hear.

He's saying that every [deterministic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_context-free_grammar) context-free grammar can be systematically rewritten to a *different* grammar for the same language (i.e. one that generates the same set of token strings) which is LL(1).

"Deterministic" is an important restriction and stronger than it sounds -- the Wikipedia article notes that not every *unambiguous* CFG qualifies as "deterministic".

Comment: I think you right watching it again. My mistake.